# Upload key on GoogleCloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, key

I need to upload a key on GoogleCloud Platform, but the platform says that key needs to be Public certificates need to be in RSA_X509_PEM format. I'm kinda of stuck and don't how to upload the key. Did anyone came across the same situation and ca help [googlecloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZIa1.png)

Comment: Of which type of key are you talking about?

Comment: It's a key that I created on service account for a project

Comment: Edit your question to show the steps used to create the key. Include the first line of the key which shows the format. There are many key formats and encodings. An RSA_X509_PEM is an RSA_PEM public key wrapped in a X509V3 certificate. The header line should contain `----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` Suggestion: unless you must manage your own private keys, use the other option and download the Google private key in JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to "upload a key on a service account", that means that you have generated a private key on your side, in the correct format, and you want to send to Google the public key to let google validate validate the communication.

If you follow [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#uploading) you have the correct openSSL command to generate a key for this use case.

Comment: I did generate a key in json but I don't quite understand how to upload on the key now in RSA_X509_PEM format. The documentation is not very clear

Comment: On the screen you posted click "browse", select the public key you made (it will be something like **public_key.pem**) and click on "upload"

Comment: @Marie. It's 2 different things. Either you ask a key to Google on a service account. And you download a private key in embedded in JSON file (and because Google has generated the private key, it keep automatically the public part on its side, no need to upload it). The second case is in the documentation: you generate the keypair on your side and you need to inform Google of the public part to plug on the service account object.

Comment: thank you for the explanation @guillaumeblaquiere :)

Comment: The relevant upload instructions have been moved slightly: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-upload